# Java - JComboBox Invalidade Item Selection in ItemListener

Tags: java, selection, jcombobox, invalidation

I am trying to add a condition inside my ItemListener and only if the condition is verified the item gets selected, otherwise I dont want the user to be able to select that item.

How can I invalidade a selection on item listener? Make a new selection inside the item listener? won't that be a infinite loop? :o

Thanks alot in advance.
Here is my code:

```
private final class classeComboBoxItemListener implements ItemListener {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {


            try {
                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)
                    updateLabelLugares(true, (Classe) e.getItem());

                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    updateLabelLugares(false, (Classe) e.getItem());
            } catch (Exception e1) {


                /// HERE I WANT TO INVALIDATE THE SELECTION
                /// Returning to the item selected before!

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: `How can I invalidade a selection on item listener?` - remove the item from the model. If will be frustrating for a user to see an item and then click on it only to discover they can't select it. Of course the user will try multiple times and then report a bug because they can't select the value.

Comment: Yes I can do that, didnt think about it, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I invalidade a selection on item listener? Make a new
>   selection inside the item listener? won't that be a infinite loop? :o

- remove `ItemListener` from `JComboBox`, then call `JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1)`, add `ItemListener` back to `JComboBo`x (standard and good practicies)
- create two void (standard and good practicies) in one add listener, in second remove listener
- don't wrap `if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)` inside `boolean` for the reason, to block code executions untill reset status ended
- use `if - else` for `if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED){ .... } else { ... }`